# MongoDB ensureIndex: Connection reset by peer

Tags: mongodb

I have documents which contain a geo field like the below.

```
"geo" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
        37.44609999,
        -121.88355687
    ]
},
```

When I try to add a spatial index to this collection, it thinks for a while and then I get an error.

```
db.data.ensureIndex({'geo.coordinates': '2dsphere'})

Sat Sep 28 17:49:33.451 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017
Sat Sep 28 17:49:33.494 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017] 
Sat Sep 28 17:49:33.497 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Sat Sep 28 17:49:33.634 Error: error doing query: failed at src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
Sat Sep 28 17:49:33.650 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Sat Sep 28 17:49:33.654 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Any idea why this is happening? How can I debug this further?

Comment: Can you tell us your mongodb version?

Comment: According to db.serverStatus() I am running Mongo version 2.4.6.
My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figure it out. I have Mongo installed on an Amazon EC2 Micro Instance. By default micro instances come with 613MB of memory and no swap space.

The spatial index I was trying to create was over approximately 1 million documents. So my guess is creating this index used up all available RAM and so with no swap space the Linux kernel had no choice but to kill the Mongo process.

The solution for anyone out there having the same problem is to follow this tutorial http://cloudstory.in/2012/02/adding-swap-space-to-amazon-ec2-linux-micro-instance-to-increase-the-performance/

Comment: Does anyone know if when this error occurs the index is still created properly?  The mongo service seemingly starts fine, but, is the index actually okay?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson I once had a similar problem. Later had to rebuild the index due to weird performance issues